# SubreportProcessing Event not Firing

Tags: c#, reporting-services, subreport

the subreportprocess eventhandler not firing when try debug

```
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\sale_dept.rdl";
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(addsubreport);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();




 void addsubreport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();

           SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("subreportquery", conn);

           SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
           dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);

           e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("discount", dataset.Tables[0]));
        }
```

the above handler is not firing when i run the pgm in debug mode.

Comment: renaming the subreport extensions from .rdl to .rdlc solved the issue

Comment: Can you post that as an answer and mark it as accepted. It might help future users.

Comment: @anupagrawal answered with my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue. I am posting it as answer because it may help someone in future.

The SubreportProcessingEventHandler will only get fired for .rdlc subreports. In my project main report and all subreports are .rdl extension. So only change I done was went to command prompt and renamed the subreport extension as .rdlc

eg:- ren discount.rdl discount.rdlc

Then attach the data-set for the sub-report accordingly.

See the code as below

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\main_rpt.rdl";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(addsubreport);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


void addsubreport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{

SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

Switch(e.ReportPath)
{
case "subreport1":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport one", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport1", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;
case "subreport2":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport two", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport2", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;
case "subreport3":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport three", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport3", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;

 }

}
```

Switch is needed if you have more than one sub-report. Main point to notice

1.All sub-report should have extension .rdlc

2.if any parameter is passing make sure it is also named correctly.

3. Specify the path correctly. It's better to put main report and subreport in same folder.

Now run the C# application it will show the main report with all sub-report